# Why is my flag still pending

Tags: support, flags

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49248941/cant-fadeout-specific-element-within-array/49249143#49249143) answer as "In need of moderator intervention" with the comment

> Ans is copy from above answer.

Now the answer is deleted but on the flag list my flag is still pending. Maybe I am missing something about the flag in need of moderator intervention with comment.

[image: Screenshot of Flags for Shree Khanal. The post title is in red, indicating it has been deleted, and the flag is listed as "pending".]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Custom flags do not go away once content is deleted. They'll only be actioned once a moderator reviews it.

Currently, there's a large backlog in the moderator queue.. one of the reasons for the current [election](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) taking place.

They'll get to it, just be patient.